# How to achieve "pixelated/squared" image loading effect like they did it on Palantir website

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

How to achieve "pixelated/squared" image loading effect like they did it on Palantir website: https://www.palantir.com/
Images do not need to move into the view like there, I only need the animation where these squares become a full picture

I have searched on google but can't find a single example of this type of loading

Comment: AFAIK you can only do this with canvas, CSS filters don't have this kind of effect (yet?). Here's a post that does what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56607662/if-you-can-animate-the-pixelated-canvas-squares-in-javascript

Comment: It's like progressive image loading.
https://jmperezperez.medium.com/more-examples-of-progressive-image-loading-f258be9f440b